# Install MIME in meteor

Tags: meteor, mime, woff

I got this when I tried to use certain font in Meteor:

> Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type
>   font/x-woff:

I've tried `meteor add mime` or `npm install mime` command, none worked.

Anybody know about this?

Answer (score 0):

> Npm support for Meteor comes to the light from version 0.6.0. But it
>   gives complete NPM access to packages only.

http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html

if you are trying to use a font. put it into public/ directory not anywhere else.